# Thread wait for Server/Client before proceeding

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

How do I synchronize threads while using one server and multiple clients?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    // Creates and starts instance of the "Server" class
    Server s = new Server();
    s.start();
    
    // Creates and starts 2 instances of the "Client" class
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        Client c = new Client();
        c.start();
    }
        
}
```

My output looks like this: `Please enter number: Please enter number:`

But it should look like this:

`Please enter number:` *User enters number*

`Please enter number:` *User enters number*

Both client and server classes are looking familiar like this:

```
public class Client extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Aren't the clients supposed to be on different machines?

Comment: It's a school task and it says that I need to create multiple client classes which are running after another... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for this [Thread.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join())

How to use it?

If you have one client, say
`Client client1 = new Client();`

And you want that another client should run after this client has finished its task, then you create a new client like this.

```java
client1.start();
client1.join();
Client client2 = new Client();
client2.start();
```

You can use it in loop like this:

```java
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.start();
    client.join();
}
```

How does it work?

Performing `join()` on a thread makes the thread that started this new thread to go into a waiting state. It remains in waiting state until the thread that `join()` was performed upon terminates or is interrupted.
Any code after `join()` is not executed until the thread on which this method was called, terminates.

In your case, the main thread goes into waiting state.